# Share IOS app twice between Apple ID's

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-id, sharing

A while back, I got a friend to share an app with me which was no longer on the app store. He logged in to his Apple ID on my iPhone, went to 'Purchased', and downloaded the app for me(Which, according to Apple, is perfectly legal- the app was free to get).

Now, I'd like to transfer the app to another friend. However, the app in question doesn't show up in my 'Purchased', because I never downloaded it from the app store. Is there any way I can give that app to my friend without the use of my first friend's Apple ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The app was never shared to your Apple ID and was not associated with your Apple ID in any way. If the app was still on the store and needed updating, your friend's Apple ID would be used. The app remains bound to your friend's Apple ID and thus you need your friend's Apple ID again to install it elsewhere.

Comment: @grgarside-Is there anyway for me to associate that app with my apple ID, or for my friend to share it with me?

Comment: No, there isn't.  You never owned the app nor was it associated with your Apple ID, as @grgarside mentioned.  You're not able to do what your friend did because, according to what you mentioned, the app is no longer in the App Store.